# unable to post tweet on python 3.4 and twitter-1.14.2 api

Tags: python, twitter

```
 from twitter.api import Api

 Api = twitter.api(consumer_key='[gdgfdfhgfuff] ',
                   consumer_secret='[jhhjf] ',
                    access_token_key=' [jhvhvvhjvhvhvh]',
                    access_token_secret='[hvghgvvh] ')

 friends=Api.PostUpdate("First Tweet from PYTHON APP ")
```

error given

```
TTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from twitter.api import Api
ImportError: cannot import name 'Api'
```

I am using python 3.4 and twitter-1.14.2 api

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`from twitter.api import Api`

with

`from twitter.api import Twitter`

There is no class or method in [`twitter.api`](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py) called `Api`

Comment: Don't use `import *`.

Comment: @AlexThornton Added it only because the documentation of the package used that in their example.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter package which you are using has no `Api` class.

Source Code link : https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py

You have to use this as

```
from twitter.api import Twitter
twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth(
                token, token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))
```